# proper standard http header for website that updates frequently

Tags: php, html, browser-cache, pagespeed, yslow

According to Yahoo YSLOW documentation and internet, it states that I need to have it where served web documents must expire at least 49 hours in the future from now for it to have a good grade in the speed test. I cache both documents and images on the website for optimal performance. The problem is when content is updated, some browsers reload the images correctly while other browsers use the old stale content. An immediate fix is the mandatory use of the refresh button, but I want to try to avoid having users to use it.

This is my header setup so far. I written it in PHP. If you don't understand PHP, just ignore "header(" and ",true".

```
header("ETag: \"".md5(time())."\"",true);
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time() - 3600).' GMT',true);
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time()+(3600*24*7)).' GMT',true);
header('Cache-control: max-age:'.(3600*24*7).', public',true);
header("Age: 0",true);
header("Connection: close",true);
```

Basically I set the document to expire one week later and I want to change that.

Anyways.... What I am asking is for a way to create a proper set of headers in a way where users don't have to force-reload a page because of their browser (I'm assuming firefox), and I also want to meet google pagespeed insights and yahoo's YSLOW standards.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to add that the website is updated two to five times a week where most of the updates happen over the weekend.

Comment: header dates based on file\contnet edited dates  makes sense to me

Comment: Well, for things updated that often, I just wouldn't cache it, but then again, I'm not trying to do well on any speed tests. For such a situation where you want caching but updating frequently, I would use the application cache, as it provides results that are generally faster than the normal cache and reduces bandwidth, and you can easily administer updates as often as you want and it'll still be effective. However, YSLOW and Google Pagespeed will count the application cache as a valid caching mechanism (it's an HTML5 feature)

Answer (score 0):

The point of setting cache-control headers with a long expiration time is to *make* the browser use old responses for longer instead of frequently checking back with the server.  If you want the browser to check frequently for new content, you can't specify a long cache lifetime; the two are diametrically opposed.

What you can do, however, is specify long cache lifetimes for things that don't change often and don't need to be seen immediately by the browser, such as scripts and stylesheets, while keeping the cache lifetime short for frequently-updated content.  You can have the browser check regularly for updated images, but only check for new scripts and stylesheets once per week, for example.

Also, even for frequently-changing content like your images — and especially for large files like images — you'll want to support conditional requests, so the browser can avoid re-downloading the content of resources that haven't actually changed.  The way to do that is:

- Provide proper `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers, representing the current state of the resource, in your HTTP responses.
- Based on those response headers, the browser can include `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers in future requests for the same resource.
- The server can examine those request headers and send a 304 Not Modified response if they match the current state of the resource; this tells the browser that its cached copy is still valid.  If the headers don't match — meaning that the resource has changed — then send the new version of the resource together with new `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers.

You're currently sending `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers in your responses, but they're useless because they're based on the current system time, which changes constantly.  From a cache-management standpoint, the file appears to have "changed" every second (when the return value of `time()` changes).  Your `Last-Modified` header should be the file's modification timestamp, and your `ETag` should be something like a hash of its contents.

Comment: I also use adsense on the site so if pagespeed thinks my site is doing worse, chances are i may make less money. I can understand what you're saying, and I also do have the 304 response functionality on the site already setup (which I didn't show the code for).

Comment: You're misinterpreting a general guideline as a hard rule — you can be sure that Google and Yahoo don't specify 49-hour caching for your inbox contents in GMail and Yahoo Mail.  Use caching intervals that make sense for your content.

Comment: Real-world example:  the front page of Facebook has caching suppressed completely for the HTML and the AJAX data feed, but all the scripts, stylesheets, and icon images come from a CDN (Akamai) with year-long caching.